# gcp container-os with OS login and IAM admin asking for sudo password?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, sudo

I'm running cos `VERSION_ID=85 BUILD_ID=13310.1209.17` and I love the web ssh console. It was bugging me to enable OS Login to speed up authentication so I finally did it.

The user i'm logging in with has the following IAM roles:

- Compute OS Admin Login
- Owner

Before OS login, I could click the SSH button and open a web console and execute admin commands without using `sudo`. With OS Login I have to use `sudo`, but when I do `sudo`, it is asking me for a password. Since these SSH keys and PAM is managed by google what password is it looking for? How do i set this up correctly?

I turned off OS Login and I can now `sudo` without a password.

Comment: With or without OS Login, `sudo` is required to run admin commands except if you are logged in as the user `root` or equivalent. More details are required for the command and the user where `sudo` is requesting a password. Provided that the user is part of the `sudoers` group, a password is not required. Note: the exact method and configuration is OS dependent.

Comment: before turning on OS login, using latest cos, I would click the SSH button in the console and it would log me in and I could type sudo commands without a password. Once I turned on OS login I did the same thing and it asks me for a password.

Comment: Having password protected `sudo` makes your system more secure. Have you tried to change sudo configuration with `visudo`?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might still be facing this issue:
You can get root priviliges without entering a password by using `sudo su` command.